# restore deleted files in specific directory in centos(vps)

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

I accidentally removed all files in my /etc/yum.repos.d directory

```
yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
repolist: 0

yum install svn
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
There are no enabled repos.
  Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
  To enable Red Hat Subscription Management repositories:
     subscription-manager repos --enable <repo>
  To enable custom repositories:
     yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

how to restore files for specific directory?

Comment: Do you have snapshot? If no find similar machine (same distribution) and copy the files.

Comment: Thank you @RomeoNinov, i will try it

Answer (score 2):

you cannot just magically restore all files, we cannot know which repositories you had.

The best thing you could do is look at a similar machine (also redhat) and look at the files. If it is the same os and version, you can just copy the files. This way you can at least re-enable the default repositories and probably epel.